# Sync and Core Api's folderName and fileName character limits?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

Hi I was wondering what the character limit for creating a folderName or fileName on the api?
I found this article, how accurate is it and how does it affect my app when it is syncing to the desktop ? https://www.dropbox.com/help/145/en

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a similar limit in the API/SDK itself (though you may run into issues with very long URLs when trying to make the API call itself),  but you should consider that article accurate and keep that in mind. Changes made in the API do sync to desktop clients linked to the same Dropbox account, so if you need compatibility, you may want to check the length yourself in your app.